# Zend Framework 2 'quote_identifiers' => false

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

So i was planning my Application when i've encountered the following issue:
i want to be able to make this query using Zend Db Select:

SELECT  `COLUMN_NAME` AS  `COLUMN_NAME` 
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   WHERE  `TABLE_NAME` =  'brand'
   AND  `TABLE_SCHEMA` =  'product'

that selects the colums from a table. The problem is that Zend generates:

SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` AS `COLUMN_NAME` 
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
   WHERE `TABLE_NAME`    = 'brand' AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'product'

with "``"(quotes) on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMS that produces a SQL error of "No database selected".
I've tried to insert " 'platform_options' => array('quote_identifiers' => false)," in my configuration array but nothing happens.
The code used to generate that is:

```
    $sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
    $select = $sql->select();
    $select->columns(array('COLUMN_NAME'),false);
    $select->from('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS');
    $select->where(array('TABLE_NAME' => $table,'TABLE_SCHEMA' => $database));
    $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
    var_dump($sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select));
```

Comment: Not an answer to the problem with quote identifiers, but based on what you're querying here, you might want to look at `Zend\Db\Metadata` -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.db.metadata.html

Comment: @Crisp I will check this solution and come back with a response. However the question remains can you resolve the quoting problem without the metadata help?10q

Comment: @Crisp The usage of the metadata has helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back with you on this issue, I managed to find an answer for prefixing tables with the schema name. [Here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6120) you can find the issue described and the solution seems to be the Zend TableIdentifier. So, to make a small conclusion the solution for the information schema / tables / columns is Metadata and for prefixing with a schema name is Table identifier.If you CAN'T remove the quotes just use one of these solutions